# How to query for photos in a certain album

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**PhotosInAlbums Table**

[image]

**Photos Table**
[image]

Using the `$mysqli->query()`, I want to return all the rows where the photo_id in the Photos Table matches the photo_id in the PhotoInAlbums with the same album_id. So essentially, return the information (id, title, date_created, date_modified, file_path) for photos in the same album, so I can display those photos in a table. How do I do this? Also, my query for `$results2` returns false and I don't know why.

**Code**

```
//Gets album id from form
$album_id = $_GET['album_id'];

//Returns all photo_id for photos in that album
$result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT photo_id FROM PhotosInAlbum WHERE album_id = $album_id"); //RETURNS FALSE WHY?

//Returns all the rows where the photo_id matches Photos tables' id
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Photos WHERE id = $result2");

    while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 print('<div class = "cell">
                <div class = "photo_container" >

        $title = $row[ 'title'];
        $file_path = $row[ 'file_path' ];

        print('<img class = "photo_image" src = "'.$file_path.'" alt = "default album" width = "300"/>
        print('<div class = "photo_title">'.$title.' ('.$credit.')</div>');               
        print('  </div>
            </div>');
    }
```